# build.gradleのSyncを解決できない

Tags: android, gradle

AndroidのプロジェクトでKotlinのバージョンを`1.1.4-3`から`1.2.41`へアップデートしたところgradleのSyncが通らなくなってしまいました。
Syncを実行すると

```
Failed to resolve: firebase-analytics-impl
Failed to resolve: play-services-stats
Failed to resolve: firebase-common
Failed to resolve: play-services-base
Failed to resolve: play-services-basement
```

というログが出力されます。
この状態でビルドを実行すると

```
Could not find firebase-analytics-impl.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2).
Searched in the following locations:
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-analytics-impl/15.0.2/firebase-analytics-impl-15.0.2.aar
```

というログが出力されます。

ログに従ってプラグインを`compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2'`のように追加してもログは減りません。
また、最新版が公開されているものもバージョンを最新にしてみても何も変化はありませんでした。
さらに、GooglePlayに関してはSDKを確認し、Google Play servicesの49とGoogle Repositoryの58がインストールされているのを確認しました。

思いつく限りの手を試したのですがどうにも出来ず困っています。
アドバイスを頂けると幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

### gradleの設定

プロジェクトのgradleは次の通り

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.41'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.1'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

アプリのgradleは次のようにしています

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:preference-v14:26.1.0'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

のjcenterとmavenを逆にしてみてはどうでしょうか

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()
    }
}
```